# Missing SpringBeanJobFactory in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-4

Looking at upgrading from Spring 3.2.3 to 4.1, this class seems to have disappeared,is there a migration path for it? is it perhaps just not pulled in by Spring core anymore?

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be in `spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar`.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: does not appear to be `spring-context` was already defined, and I updated dated it to 4.1.4

Comment: though your answer alludes to it actually being in `-support`

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand. Is the dependency was already there? Are you still having the compile time issue?

Comment: it was in `spring-context-support` not `spring-context`, the `spring-context` artifact doesn't contain that class

Comment: Is there a reason why some Quartz related classes are in spring-context-support instead of spring-context ? Is it a backport from spring 5 ?